# Choose the part containing error

Tags: word-choice

The only indian (1)/ to win the Nobel Prize for literature (2)/ was Ravindra Nath Tagore. (3)/ No error (4)
I think in the part 2, there should be **who win** at the place of **to win**. But my book says 'no error'. Please help.

Comment: Both _Indian_ and _Literature_ should have a capital letter (as a nationality and part of the official name for the prize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the book says correct.There is no error at all.

Here, the part you are talking with- `"to win the Nobel Prize for literature"` is an infinitive phrase used as adjective which modifies the noun `'The only indian'` and implying the exact meaning you are thinking now which is- `"who won the Nobel Prize for literature"`